# Dynamic PL/SQL function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to use the following PL/SQL function - oracle.

```
FUNCTION GET_RECORDS_FOR_REFRESH( KEY_ARRAY IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR

    IS  RET_DATA SYS_REFCURSOR;
        SQL_QUEURY VARCHAR2(32767);

    BEGIN

        SQL_QUEURY:= 'SELECT * FROM PASSESNGERS WHERE ' || KEY_ARRAY ;

        OPEN RET_DATA FOR SQL_QUEURY;

        RETURN RET_DATA;

    END; 
END;
```

KEY_ARRAY contains a comma separated values with column name attached. For example KEY_ARRAY = 'PAS_PROF_ID IN (15236,85694,45863,59456,42387)'

Although this function has no compilation errors, it results following error at runtime.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 62:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
```

Can someone please tell me what's the mistake here and what I should do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` and check the query formation before executing it.

Comment: How do you call your function in `JDBC` ?

Comment: Oh wait, your function has a compilation error for sure. There are two END statements.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>     END; 
> END;
> ```

This might be silly, but I see you have two `END` statements in the PL/SQL code you have shared. Probably this is the reason you are getting `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following`.

> Although this function has no compilation errors, it results following error at runtime.

PLS error is a compile time error. Remove one of the **END**s, and **recompile**.

Also, it is a good practice to use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` and first check the query formation before actually executing it in the code.